# 2d_array random numbers (10Rows, 6 COLS) not repeated to file C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I need to streamwrite into a file.txt a 10 random numbers combinations (NOT REPEATED) like lottery program. I got everything except Non-repeated random numbers. it has to be seen (file.txt) like a 2D array with 10 combinations thx.

```
class Matriz
{
    private int[,] array;
    private int nfilas, ncols;     

    public void Ingresar()
    {
        Random aleatori = new Random();
        nfilas = 10;
        ncols = 6;
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        array = new int[nfilas, ncols];
        for (int filas = 0; filas < nfilas; filas++)
        {
            for (int columnas = 0; columnas < ncols; columnas++)
                array[filas, columnas] = aleatori.Next(0, 50);
        }
    }

    public void Imprimir()
    {
        StreamWriter fitxer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\andres\lotto649.txt");
        int contador = 0;
        for (int f = 0; f < nfilas; f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < ncols; c++)                    
                fitxer.Write(array[f, c] + " ");

            fitxer.WriteLine();
            contador++;
        }
        fitxer.WriteLine($"\n\n\tHay {contador} combinaciones de la Loteria 6/49");
        fitxer.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Matriz array_menu = new Matriz();
        array_menu.Ingresar();
        array_menu.Imprimir();           
       
    }
}
```

Comment: it actually works(compile,write out) but its generating repeated combinations in same rows. how to solve it?

Comment: I assume you only want to avoid duplicates per row. I think the easiest solution would be to track the numbers written for that row and, if the next random number is already contained, just keep generating new numbers until you get one that isn't yet in the list.

Comment: The basic idea is: make a list of your 50 numbers, then get one number randomly and remove that number from the list, then get the next one until the list is empty or you have enough numbers.

Comment: @jack-t-spades  yes its only about avoid duplicates per row , you suggest to use if (nums.Contains (aleatori)) conditional? something like this?

Comment: Unrelated: I'd suggest to create a static Random object as class field rather than a local one.

Comment: _"you suggest to use if (nums.Contains (aleatori)) conditional?"_ that would be one solution to that problem, yes. Another would be to have a List of your numbers, then randomly pick an index into the list and remove the picked item. That way you _always_ pick a distinct value even if RND spits out the same index twice in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.
Before inserting the new number in the given position, check the row thus far if the same number is already in there and if so, repeat the process until you get a number that isn't yet in there.

```cs
for (int filas = 0; filas < nfilas; filas++)
{
  for (int columnas = 0; columnas < ncols; columnas++)
  {
    bool cont = true;
    while(cont)
    {
      cont = false;
      int newRand = aleatori.Next(0, 50);
      for(int i = 0; i < columnas; i++)
        if(array[filas, i] == newRand)
          cont = true;
      if(cont)
        continue;
      array[filas, columnas] = newRand;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, since the number is small you could also work with a list of ints and remove the given value from there.

This has the advantage, that you'll never have to redo your random number as it will always produce a valid result. The above example could (theoretically) run indefinitely long.

```cs
for (int filas = 0; filas < nfilas; filas++)
{
  List<int> nums = new List<int>(49);
  for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
    nums.Add(i + 1); //num 1...49

  for (int columnas = 0; columnas < ncols; columnas++)
  {
    int index = aleatori.Next(0, nums.Count)
    array[filas, columnas] = nums[index];
    nums.RemoveAt(index);
  }
}
```